# Expansion of Schubert polynomials into standard elementary monomials

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, schubert-calculus

I have an explicit formula for expressing any Schubert polynomial in terms of standard elementary monomials that may or may not be cancelation-free. I haven't determined this yet, but it seems likely that it is. Before I put too much effort into proving this, though, I'm having trouble determining what we could gain from this, and I thought I'd put the question to the experts on this who lurk around here. It may also not even be new, in the sense that such a formula may already exist.

So the question is: what would an explicit, cancelation-free formula for expressing a Schubert polynomial in terms of standard elementary monomials gain us, if such a formula is not already known?

Any references on the topic would be welcome as well.

Comment: It seems like this has been explored to a significant degree. Maybe reading the introduction of the recent paper https://doi.org/10.1007/s00026-021-00558-z can explain some of the significance of SEM expansions of Schubert polynomials

Comment: @SamHopkins Thanks Sam. Simply from reading the abstract and given how recent this is, the answers to the questions "would it matter" and "is it new" would both be a resounding yes. Now to actually look at the paper.

Comment: Yes, I would say so, though I'm not an expert. It was nice meeting you this weekend by the way!

Comment: @SamHopkins Indeed, you too. I've looked at 5 papers now from the references of what you sent, and what it gives us is a formula for quantum Schubert polynomials. However, it's entirely possible to compute the SEM expansion with cancelation without too much insight, so I still don't know what we gain from cancelation-free.  One paper says, "In other words, the ``trivialization of quantization''
achieved by [FGP] reduces the understanding of quantum Schubert polynomials to the ``really hard part'' of understanding the SEM expansions of
ordinary Schubert polynomials." What's hard about it?

Comment: @SamHopkins After investigation it seems like it would be a miracle if my method is cancelation free, so it's quite likely it isn't, but I know it is pretty efficient because I use it for my calculation software and it's reasonable even for $n=15$.